# Polyalphabetic cipher

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program for polyalphabetic cipher. I have this section of code:

```
while (i != 4 && count != cipherlen) {
    if ((((int) ciphertext.charAt(i)) - 65) == 0) {
        plaintext[count] = (char) (90 - (((int) keyreader.charAt(i)) - 65));
    }

    if ((((int) keyreader.charAt(i)) - 65) > (((int) ciphertext
            .charAt(i)) - 65)) {
        System.out.println("first");

        plaintext[count] = ((char) (90 - ((((int) keyreader.charAt(i)) - (65)) - (((int) ciphertext
                .charAt(i)) - 65))));
        //System.out.println(text);
    }
    else {
        //System.out.println("second");
        plaintext[count] = ((char) ((((int) ciphertext.charAt(count)) - ((int) keyreader
                .charAt(i))) + 64));
    }
}
```

Its working properly for all the cases except when it encounters a value of, suppose cipher text is A then I am subtracting 65, in that case its giving some dummy value.

Could you please help me determine what the problem is?

Let `AAAD` be the key and `NIFQFWBACP` be the ciphertext, then the plain text generated is `MHEMEVA=BO`

Comment: please somebody help..

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `char` is a numeric type.  You can do arithmetic on `char` values without casting to some other type.

So, lets start by translating your code into something equivalent that is vaguely readable ...

```
while (i != 4 && count != cipherlen) {
    if (ciphertext.charAt(i) == 'A') {
        plaintext[count] = 'Z' - (keyreader.charAt(i) - 'A');
    }

    if (keyreader.charAt(i) > ciphertext.charAt(i)) {
        System.out.println("first");

        plaintext[count] = 'Z' - (keyreader.charAt(i) - 'A') - 
                           (ciphertext.charAt(i) - 'A');
        //System.out.println(text);
    }
    else {
        //System.out.println("second");
        plaintext[count] = ciphertext.charAt(count) - 
                           keyreader.charAt(i) + ('A' - 1));
    }
}
```

At this point I would observe:

- I cannot discern from your code what you are *trying* to do.  It simply makes no sense.
- What you are actually doing *appears* at first glance to not be a reversible encryption.
- I've no idea what you mean by "dummy value" in this context.
- Since you don't change `count` or `cipherlen` or `i`.  The loop body either executes zero times, or an infinite number of times.  This contradicts what you said in your question about it "working properly" for most cases.

It would help if you provide a description *in English* of the enciphering process you are trying to implement here, together with a clear statement of what you expect to see AND what you actually see.